# Traveling to London as a nominal Muslim

Tags: uk, london, religion, islam

I am a 19-year-old boy and I want to travel alone to Great Britain, primarily London, as a tourist, also a future immigrant. Since I was born and raised in Iran and born to Muslim parents, I'm known as a Muslim person in my country (however I'm not Muslim).

Since I heard things about misbehavior toward tourists and immigrants, especially Muslim people, I want to make sure that is it really safe for me to travel alone to such a place. I'm staying only for a week.

Comment: Be respectful of others, and I would expect you won't have any problems.  Don't be surprised if security guards, police, etc. ask you questions - just be relaxed and give honest answers.

Comment: It's a sad comment on either this community or the world when a question that is basically asking "will my religion cause me to be unsafe whilst in the UK" is closed as "opinion-based" - especially without anyone actually commenting on why they through it was opinion-based.  Voting to re-open.

Comment: It's unclear what the OP means by "really safe". Does that mean as safe as a rice paddy in rural China? As safe as Toronto? As safe as the Chicago Loop area? As safe as the South Side of Chicago in broad daylight?

Comment: Do you look Muslim and worry about people reaction to that or are you worried about being an apostate in a Muslim area?

Comment: See #12 in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_mosques

Comment: I've already got my visa and I'll be traveling next week.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Keep two basic facts in mind:

- Nobody in London will care what the Iranian government declares your religion to be. Most people you encounter won't even have a way to know -- and those (if any) who *can* know also know that it is difficult or impossible for people considered Muslim by Islamic governments to change that categorization.
- There are plenty of Muslims *living* in London -- about one eighth of the population self-identified as Muslim in the latest census. While some hate crimes do happen, it is not as if simply being (apparently) Muslim in London will automatically put you in urgent danger.

You can expect to meet some suspicion just for being a citizen of a country that is generally considered to be hostile to the west and often named as a state sponsor of terrorism. Your personal religious stance (or lack of same) does not factor appreciably into that. If you encounter questioning from authorities, your only option is generally to grin and bear it -- give honest answers and things should eventually sort themselves out.

Additionally, being a young man from the Middle East with weak ties to your home country (they must be weak, since you declare an intention to emigrate eventually) will make you look like an immigration risk, which can create trouble for you getting permission to enter the UK at all. Once you manage to get a visa, though, that hurdle will mostly be passed.